# PDF document does not contain utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, web

I am making an application on Django. You need to add html page to PDF document. The document is being created, but the Cyrillic alphabet is smeared with squares.

```
#views.py
def fetch_pdf_resources(uri, rel):
    if uri.find(settings.MEDIA_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ''))
    elif uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ''))
    else:
        path = None
    return path


def export_pdf(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Application, pk=pk)
    template_path = 'applications/applications_detail.html'
    context = {'applications': obj, 'to_pdf': True}
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ApplicationDetail.pdf"'

    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)

    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(BytesIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), response, encoding='utf-8', link_callback=fetch_pdf_resources)
    return response


#urls.py
    path('export_pdf/', views.export_pdf, name = 'export_pdf')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common but not a very easy to fix problem. You need to use fonts that support the unicode characters for your PDF document. So, you need two things:

1. Include some fonts in your django static path (i.e copy them over to 'static/fonts'). I'm using calibri as an example (copied over from windows/fonts).
2. Use something like the following directive in your html-pdf template:

```
{% load static %}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Calibri";
    src: url({% static "fonts/calibri.ttf" %});
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Calibri";
    src: url({% static "fonts/calibrib.ttf" %});
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Calibri";
    src: url({% static "fonts/calibrii.ttf" %});
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Calibri";
    src: url({% static "fonts/calibriz.ttf" %});
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
```

3. Set a global style in your html/pdf to use calibri:

```
*, html {
    font-family: "Calibri";
    font-size:11pt;
    color: red;
}
```

The above should be enough *if* the fonts you are using actually support the characters you need *and* the fonts are found (i.e your static folders work properly) *and* you are actually overriding te fonts in your css.

For more info, you can take a look at this particular part of my pdf tutorial: https://spapas.github.io/2015/11/27/pdf-in-django/#changing-the-font-to-a-unicode-enabled-one